# Is it safe to permanently remove swap in device with huge memory?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, swap, lsblk

I have a desktop with 128G RAM. This is my typical memory usage when I am not running calculation-heavy scripts:

```
sam@debian:~$ free -ht --si
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            128G        3.3G         93G        101M         31G        124G
Swap:           975M          0B        975M
Total:          129G        3.3G         94G
```

Even when I do run simulations memory usage never surpasses 75%. So I began to question the need for a 1G `swap` partition in the first place. When I installed `Debian` I used the built-in `Use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM` option, which automatically allocated 1G for `swap`. If safe to do so, how can I remove it and have `debian--vg-root` take over the space? Below is my partition layout.

```
sam@debian:~$ lsblk -a
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                 7:0    0     0B  0 loop  
loop1                 7:1    0     0B  0 loop  
loop2                 7:2    0     0B  0 loop  
loop3                 7:3    0     0B  0 loop  
loop4                 7:4    0     0B  0 loop  
loop5                 7:5    0     0B  0 loop  
loop6                 7:6    0     0B  0 loop  
loop7                 7:7    0     0B  0 loop  
nvme0n1             259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 930.5G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 254:0    0 930.5G  0 crypt 
    ├─debian--vg-root   254:1    0 929.5G  0 lvm   /
    └─debian--vg-swap_1 254:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Comment: It's 100% safe to run without SWAP. In fact SWAP is mostly there to allow you to have more programs running than fit in your RAM. I've been running SWAPless for 20+ years now with 0 issues.

Comment: my opinion is, It's safe to do so, you'd delete the swap LV (`lvremove`) and extend the root LV (`lvresize` or `lvextend`)

Comment: Don't forget to `swapoff` first.

Comment: I recommend trying `swapoff` first, before modifying partitions, to make sure there is no performance impact. But, with that amount of physical RAM, I'm sure you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe to run without swap.  But that's the wrong question. The questions you need to ask yourself are:

1. How likely is it that my simulations will ever use more than ~128GB RAM?

   If the answer is "never", or "extremely unlikely" or similar, then you don't need swap.  You say that your sims never use more than about 75% of available RAM, so this is likely the answer.

   Note: if you're running other RAM-hungry applications (e.g. firefox or chromium) at the same time as running your sims, then take that into account - if they're using up, say, 30GB (not unlikely if you've got hundreds of windows and tabs open) and you don't want to quit them while you run the sim then having swap available will allow the kernel to swap them out and free up RAM for your sim.

   For example, on my 64GB system, firefox is currently using 21GB of RAM and chromium is using another 8.5 GB and steam is using about 3GB just idling in the background.  Together they're using about 2GB of swap on top of that. They'd have much more of their usage swapped out if I had run another memory-hungry program recently, but I haven't and I've still got about 20GB free.

   I have a total of 90GB of swap available, currently using about 6.5GB (including the 2GB used by firefox and chromium) - that's 6.5GB of idle/unused extra memory available for programs that need it.  My swap space consists of two 4GB partitions on NVME drives, another 16GB ZVOL on my NVME zfs pool (added because 8GB swap turned out to not be enough), and a 64GB ZVOL on my HDD zpool (added because using 64GB out of the 16TB in that pool is neglible). Swap priority is set to use the partitions first, then the NVME ZVOL, then the HDD ZVOL.  BTW, the reason why I only have a 16GB ZVOL for swap on my NVME pool is that the pool is only 424GB - but if it was 1TB or more, I'd put all of the ZVOL swap space on it, probably 128GB. That can wait until I upgrade my NVME drives.
2. If they ever do use more than that, the next question is "do I want them to crash when they run out of RAM or do I want them to continue running but slower?"

   If you want them to crash, then don't bother with swap.

   If you never want them to crash due to out-of-memory error, then estimate how much they're ever likely to exceed your actual RAM and add that amount of swap space.
3. Another thing to consider is "how much is the disk space used by swap actually worth"?  On a modern system with at least a terabyte or two of disk space, very little - fractions of a cent.  Contrast that with the cost (in time or money or annoyance) of a sim crashing due to an out-of-memory error and having to be run again.   Swap is useful and it's better to have it but not need it than need it and not have it.